# Adding and Displaying List Object

Tags: java, spring

Im developing a web app in spring and trying to display a list of all staff in my db using the following code

```
@PostMapping("/request_list")
 public List <Staff> processCreationForm(Model model){
        var sList = (List<Staff> staff.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("staff_list",sList);
            return "requestList";
```

for some reason this doesnt work. Please advice

Comment: do you use @Autoware

Comment: i dont know what that is. Im very new to programming in java and spring

Comment: ```staff.findAll()``` how create staff object?

Comment: private Staff staff; at declaration.

Comment: use this ```@Autoware private Staff staff;```

Comment: doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203497/discussion-between-b-obed-and-istiaque-hossain).

Answer (score 0):

Adds `@ResponseBody` on method name `processCreationForm` then you can return `sList`.

```
@PostMapping("/request_list")
@ResponseBody
public List <Staff> processCreationForm(Model model){
    return (List<Staff> staff.findAll());
```

Spring will use Jackson convert `List<Staff>` to json array.

Try to this tutorial >>> https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: how then is the html page served?

Comment: ```@ResponseBody``` tag can provide only data ..... no view page

Comment: ok then. I need a page the displays data(in this case its called 'requestList'). How do i go about that

Comment: @B.obed If you needs to serve as html page try to return ModelAndView instead of List<Staff>